# facebook feed url with Link parameter is not working on latest version

Tags: facebook, feed

/{user-id}/feed

Link parameter is not working when i am share image.

Please suggest me, is any alternate to share image on facebook page using feed url

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "*Link parameter is not working*"?

What happens when you make a POST request to `/me/feed` with `link=
https://my_image_url.png`?